# what's the maximum volume of a cone with a 10 cm generator

Tags: calculus

i have no idea how to solve this i tried writing down the volume expression depending on the angle $ v= \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h $ knowing that $ r= 10\sin\theta $ and $h= 10\cos\theta $ then $ V= \frac{1000}{3}\pi(\sin^2\theta \cos\theta) $ and that way the volume would deppend on the angle of the generator to the axis and i thought to differentiate the function of the volume in order to find the maximum value $ \frac{dv}{d\theta}= \frac{1000\pi}{3}\sin\theta ( 3 \cos^3\theta -1) $ this is simplifying at much as i can but i can't see a way to solve it for zero

Comment: @T.Bongers : A generator of a cone is a line that runs through the vertex of the cone, and which, when revolved about the cone's axis, yields a surface of revolution that is the cone.  The term has been standard for probably at least a couple of centuries.

Comment: In problems of this sort, much of the skill lies in choosing the right independent variable. I think that the difficulty you ran into shows that the angle is not the best choice. Why don’t you try the radius of the base of the cone instead?

Comment: but without a fixed angle i can't write the height in the terms of the radius there for i end up with two variables the height and the radius

Comment: Ah, but you know the relation between the height and radius, on’counta the generator has length $10$ cm.

Comment: Whoops, looking at it closely, I see that the clever choice of indep. variable is really the altitude. (Sorry)

Comment: well i can't see how choosing the altitude h as the variable will yield me the equation without an angle if i make the relation between the radius and altitude the angle is needed $ r= 10sin\theta $ and $ 10^2 = h^2 + r^2 $

Comment: Please forget all about the angle. What is the relation between the radius and the altitude, knowing that the generator has length $10$ cm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle seems fine to me as a variable, but since it the formula contains $r^2$ the function should be $v(\theta)=\cfrac {1000\pi}3\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta$. Then you need to take care over the differentiation.

Now $\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta=(1-\cos^2\theta) \cos \theta=\cos \theta -\cos^3\theta$

So $\cfrac {dv}{d \theta}=\cfrac {1000\pi}3\left(-\sin \theta +3\sin\theta\cos^2\theta\right)$

And this expression is zero if $\sin \theta (3\cos^2\theta-1)=0$, which happens if $\sin \theta =0$ or $\cos \theta =\pm\cfrac 1{\sqrt 3}$. You just have to identify the maximum.

Comment: you are right i made a mistake as you can see i solved the derivative right i just typed it wrong, but yeah you are right how could i forget the dis junction the angle of the cosine i was so focused on the sine

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you let the independent variable be $h$, then you have $r^2+h^2=100$, so that $\frac13\pi r^2h$ becomes $\frac13\pi(100-h^2)h$, and $dV/dh=\frac13\pi(100-3h^2)$, set that to zero and you’re on your way.

Comment: so h would be $ h^2 = \frac{100}{3} = (5.773)^2 $ and $ r= 8.16 $

Comment: Right, those are the numbers I got.